# Attaching remote URL file as attachment in action mailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

I have an ActionMailer setup to send an email with an attachment from S3.  I'm doing so like this:

```
def job_apply(current_tenant, applicant)
   @current_tenant = current_tenant
   @applicant = applicant

   file = open(applicant.resume.url).read
   attachments[applicant.resume] = file

   email_with_name = "#{@current_tenant.name} <#{@current_tenant.help_email}>"
   mail(from: email_with_name, to: applicant.job.apply_email, subject: "New Job Application")
 end
```

The applicant.resume.url returns a correct URL which I can open up in the browser and retrieve the file with, however I am getting the following error:

```
Message undefined method `ascii_only?' for #<ApplicantResumeUploader:0x007fe6bc5c28a8>
File    /Users/cmalpeli/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@job_board/gems/mail-2.4.4/lib/mail/encodings.rb
Line    103
```

This is the code in encodings.rb:

```
 98     def Encodings.decode_encode(str, output_type)
 99       case
 100       when output_type == :decode
 101         Encodings.value_decode(str)
 102       else
 103         if str.ascii_only?
 104           str
 105         else
 106           Encodings.b_value_encode(str, find_encoding(str))
 107         end
 108       end
```

I'm at a bit of a loss as to where to go from here...

Any help would be appreciated...

Comment: If you comment out the line `attachments[applicant.resume] =...` does the email send correctly? If so, what are the contents of `applicant.resume`? It should be a filename string like `resume.pdf` or `resume.doc`.

Comment: Yes - it sends correct if I comment it out.  The value of `applicant.resume` is something like "resume.doc".  The value of `applicant.resume.url` is something like `something.cloudfront.net/uploads/applicant/resume/10/resume.doc'.  Opening the path in the browser initiates the download of the file.

Comment: Your question answered one problem I was facing :) Thanks! I was using `open(...)` instead of `open(...).read`. I hope you get an answer too

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is with your `applicant.resume` string in `attachments[applicant.resume]`. If this  is not a string (like a JavaScript object) and is not a filename that can represent the file that you are attaching to the email, then this will cause problems for ActionMailer.

Verify that the `applicant.resume` string is indeed a filename like `foo.pdf` or `resume.doc` before proceeding.

Comment: Is it possible the `applicant.resume` string has some strange characters inside it? As a test, if you just change the line `attachments[applicant.resume] =...` to `attachments['foo.doc'] =...` does it work?

Comment: That got me on the right path! It seems the issue was that `applicant.resume` was not a string, but was my Carrierwave uploader object.  Changing it to `applicant.resume.file_name` sent the email through w/ an attachment - however the attachment is an empty file.  I'm going to see if changing it back to `open(applicant.resume.url).read` works when I get back to my machine.

Comment: changing it back to `open(applicant.resume.url).read` worked when combined w/ `attachments[applicant.resume.filename]`.  Not sure protocol here - should I mark your answer correct or create a new Answer based on the solution I got to w/ your help?

Comment: @cman77 - glad you got it fixed. Changed answer to reflect solution to your problem if you don't mind accepting it ;)